# Getting ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE while using unirest file send with put

Tags: javascript, node.js, unirest

I am using unirest to upload a file like so

```
 unirest.put(fullUri)
    .auth({
      user: self.userName,
      pass: self.password
    })
    .header('X-Checksum-Sha1', sha1Hash)
    .header('X-Checksum-Md5', md5Hash)
    .send(fs.readFileSync(filePath))
    .end(function (response) {
```

This works fine for smaller files but for large files I get ERR_FS_FILE_TOO_LARGE error. I have already tried `max_old_space_size` without success. Looks like I can fix this by streaming the file but I can't find an api to do that in unirest js library.

Comment: What are your memory limits? Do you have enough ram to load the entire file into ram?

Comment: I know you're looking for an answer with unirest, but unirest is kind of deprecated. I recommend using axios instead.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this is an issue with `form-data` [From GitHub Issues](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-nodejs/issues/126)

---

It turns out that the unirest are using the NPM module form-data, and the form-data module requires that if it received a stream that not `fs.ReadStream`, we need to provide the file information by additional.

### Example:

```
form.append( 
  'my_file', 
  stream,
  {
    filename: 'bar.jpg', 
    contentType: 'image/jpeg', 
    knownLength: 19806,
  },
)
```

See: https://github.com/form-data/form-data#void-append-string-field-mixed-value--mixed-options-

Answer (score 0):

Streaming files with `unirest` is available via the [`.attach`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/unirest#requestattachobject-or-name-path) method:

```js
 unirest.put(fullUri)
    .auth({
      user: self.userName,
      pass: self.password
    })
    .header('X-Checksum-Sha1', sha1Hash)
    .header('X-Checksum-Md5', md5Hash)
//    .send(fs.readFileSync(filePath))
    .attach('filename', fs.createReadStream(filePath))
    .end(function (response) {
```

Comment: I already tried this and the server doesn't accept it. This is only for multipart/form-data I think

Comment: There is another way to stream data over HTTP, using `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, which is supported by the `request` package, but `unirest` doesn't seem to support it. Does your server accept any streaming method at all?

Answer (score -1):

> I can't find an API to do that in **unirest** js library.

That's because there is none: https://github.com/Kong/unirest-nodejs/issues/49:

- > You can use the underlying request library to do streaming if you want, **I am open to a pull request** either on this branch or the 1.0 version to add streaming.

Issue is still open.

---

**But** from [this issue](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-nodejs/issues/14) and from the [source code](https://github.com/Kong/unirest-nodejs/blob/a06ba4e6c58fea028d377c170cb4cbf7cf3c6049/index.js#L684) you can find out that `end()` returns `request` (see https://github.com/request/request)

```js
Unirest.request = require('request')

...

  end: function (callback) {
    ...
    Request = Unirest.request($this.options, handleRequestResponse)
    Request.on('response', handleGZIPResponse)
    ...
    return Request
  }
```

and from `request`'s source code you can find out that no actual request is sent yet (it's defered). So you can hack into it. And use it's API instead:

```js
const request = unirest.put(constants.server2)
  .auth({
    user: self.userName,
    pass: self.password
  })
  .header('X-Checksum-Sha1', sha1Hash)
  .header('X-Checksum-Md5', md5Hash)
  // .send(fs.readFileSync(filePath))
  .end(...)

fs.createReadStream(filePath).pipe(request) // just pipe it!
```

---

As a side note: *unirest* is based on *request*, *request* is [deprecated](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142) now. So... maybe you need to steer away from *unirest*.